# bintray: Unable to upload files: Could not extract metadata for artifact (from .deb)

Tags: debian, deb, bintray

I use Bintray as an APT debian repository which worked fine before.
But I have now an issue when uploading debian packages (.deb file)

```
Push to https://api.bintray.com/content/amurzeau/streamlink-debian/streamlink/0.9.0-59-g9435397+dfsg-1/pool/main/s/streamlink/livestreamer_1.12.2+streamlink+0.9.0-59-g9435397+dfsg-1_all.deb;deb_distribution=experimental;deb_component=main;deb_architecture=amd64,i386;publish=0;override=1
Response: {"message":"Unable to upload files: Could not extract metadata for artifact 'pool/main/s/streamlink/livestreamer_1.12.2+streamlink+0.9.0-59-g9435397+dfsg-1_all.deb', content might be malformed."}
```

I found that the issue was related to the content of .deb files:

- If the .deb file has `control.tar.gz` and `data.tar.gz`, it works
- If the .deb file has `control.tar.xz` and `data.tar.xz`, it fails

So the questions:

- Does bintray supports .deb package using XZ-compressed `control.tar.xz` and `data.tar.xz` ?
- Or is there something I need to do to fix the error (beside telling dpkg-deb to use GZ compression instead of XZ) ?

Note: to push debian packages to bintray from a .changes file, I use this script https://github.com/amurzeau/debian-travis/blob/c1aa5e895dc78ad44b8ae76a89871af3b93a6e23/travis-build/bintray_upload_changes.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is [indeed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446263/320370) related to the content of .deb, the compression method to be exactly.

Bintray still doesn't support packages created on Ubuntu 18.04 as of today.

It is [possible to workaround this issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480997) by specifying options to [dh_builddeb](https://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/09/17/how-to-create-debian-packages-with-alternative-compression-methods/) in the debian/rules file:

```
override_dh_builddeb:
        dh_builddeb -- --no-uniform-compression
```